# Streaming compare the contents in two directory

Tags: files, directory

How to make a streaming (in one command or script) a task for:

- compare the contents (files and folders) of the two directories dir1
  and dir2
- if new files appear in the dir1 directory, start copying them to dir2
  and simultaneously process them with a handler:

> diff -> copy -> exec some.sh

Answer (score 0):

List out the contents of dir1 to file1.txt using below command

```
ls -ltr | awk '{print $9}'  > /var/tmp/file1.txt
```

file1.txt contains this content

```
t1
1
l.sh
r.txt
l.py
l.txt
p.txt
```

List out the contents of dir2 to file2.txt using below command

```
ls -ltr | awk '{print $9}' > /var/tmp/file2.txt
```

```
t1
1
l.sh
r.txt
l.py
l.txt
```

Now this command will find the content which is not present in file2.txt when compared to file1.txt to copy to directory 2

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a) {print $1}' file2.txt file1.txt |
awk '{print "cp -rvfp" " " "directory1path”$1 " " "directory2path"}' |
sh
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by two methods:

1. Using soft link

   Use this command to get a another copy of source in destination folder

   ```
   ln -s  source destination
   ```

   but in this case once source file or directory is deleted the link will be broken and you will not be able to access it.
2. Using rsync

   ```
   rsync -avzh sourcepath destinationpath
   ```

   This command will automatically sync source and destination. Schedule a crontab for 1 minutes for this command so it continously checks and updates.

Comment: How does this achieve the part about running a handler program on the files?